# Regex to match filename containing a word, regardless of case

Tags: regex

I need a regex that matches any filename of the type `.png` containing the word `icon` in all its cases.
So it should match

```
icon.png
myicon.png
thisIcon.PnG
aniCon_this.png
ANYICON.PNG
iconno2@me.png
```

Any help appreciated!!
Thanks!
PS: I'm in java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Sebastian P mentioned:

```
/^.*icon.*\.png$/i
```

Except I'm adding the i flag to the end to mark it as case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

If you only need to verify filenames, this should do the trick:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*icon.*\\.png$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

If you get paths also, and want to extract the filename, use this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|[\\\\/])([^\\\\/]*icon[^\\\\/]*\\.png)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

To explain this one: I use negated [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for `\` and `/` to ensure that everything is part of the filename, and then I ensure that we go until the start of the filename with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

#### See also:

- [Java 6 documentation on the `Pattern` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: It would, but then `C:\icons\panda.png` would match, too.

Comment: @Sebaastin: So? That was the requirement.

Comment: @tchrist: If you re-read the requirements, it should match any *filename* that contains `icon` and ends in `.png`. If the path is `C:\icons\panda.png`, the filename does not contain `icon`, the path does.

Comment: @Sebastian: If the open(2) syscall accepts it, it is clearly a filename. The presence or absense of directory separators is a matter to be left to namei(9) to resolve for you, and has no bearing on whether you have a legal filename or not. That means that `"/"` is just as much of a filename as `"."` or `".."` or `"......."` or `"foo"` or `"foo/foo"` or `"/foo/foo/foo.foo.foo/../foofoo/..foo"` is.

Comment: @SebastianP, Though I'm sure the extra-mile is appreciated, there was no indication the original input would include a file*path*, only a file*name*. ;-)

Comment: @Brad: "filename", "pathname", and "path" are wholly synonymous. See your local kernel. A "file" is of course  different from a "filename", being related to the underlying inode rather than the path to reach it. But  there is no sense of "file path" that is different from "filename" or "pathname".

Comment: @tchrist: Now you're nitpicking. When people say filename, they usually mean the name given to a file. Most people wouldn't consider moving a file to another directory renaming the file. That said, if that's what he desires, he can just use the first regex, as it works for that case, as well.

Comment: I have to agree with Sebastian. Thanks for the input and the discussion. But if I had the same definition for "filename" like you, @tchrist I would not ask a question about such a simple regex ;)

Comment: @Sebastian: To rename => `rename - change the name of a file` on [BSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=rename&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=OpenBSD+Current&arch=i386&format=html), [Solaris](http://www.opensolarisforum.org/man/man2/rename.html), and [MacOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man2/rename.2.html). All those accept `rename("/abc/xyz","/def/xyz")` which changes its path. To change its path is to change its name. Filename and pathname have no separate meaning. Perhaps you are confusing basename. Not system programmers, eh?

Comment: @Sebastian: Your pattern fails on filenames with any of the Java newline sequences in them.  Mine doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you need is something like this:

```
(?xsiu) \A .* icon .* \. png \z
```